# Lightening and Darkening images in Python error message

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, for-loop, graphics

```
from graphics import*
#Author:
#Purpose: to lighten and darken images
#filename: lab3.py

#Purpose: to get infromation from user and send to function
#inputs:none
#outputs: picture
def main():
    choice=raw_input('press 1 to light,2 to darken')
    value=raw_input('by how much: ')
    name=raw_input('Enter name of image: ')
    temp=Image(Point(0,0),name)
    width= temp.getWidth()
    height= temp.getHeight()
    pic = Image(Point(width/2,height/2),name) 
    win=GraphWin("Original",width, height)
    if choice=='1':
        s=1- float (value)
        grey2(name,choice,pic,s).draw(win)
    if choice=='2':
        s= float(value)
        grey1(name,choice,pic,s).draw(win)
#Purpose:to darken image
#inputs: name,choice,pic,s
#outputs: return newPic
def grey1(name, choice, pic,s):
    newPic=pic.clone()
    for i in range (newPic.getHeight()):#goes through every pixel
        for f in range (newPic.getWidth()): 
            g=newPic.getPixel(f,i)
            newPic.setPixel(f,i,color_rgb(g[0]*s,g[1]*s,g[2]*s))
    return newPic
#purpose: to lighten image
#inputs: name,choice,pic,s
#outputs: return newPIc
def grey2(name, choice, pic,s):
    newPic=pic.clone()
    for i in range (newPic.getHeight()):#goes through every pixel
        for f in range (newPic.getWidth()): 
            g=newPic.getPixel(f,i)
            newPic.setPixel(f,i,color_rgb(s*g[0]+(255*s),g[1]*s+(255*s),g[2]*s+(255*s)))
    return newPic


main()
```

okay so i want it so if someone enters a 1 and enters a value between 0 and 1 it will lighten the image and if someone enters 2and enters a value between 0 and 1 it darkens the image(I think this one works?)

here are the equations I was given, why is this not working?
Shade (darken) 
    If the value of pixel p1 = (r1, g1, b1) and the amount of desired change is s (<= 1.0) 
    Then the value of the new pixel, p2 = 
    r2 = r1 * s 
    g2 = g1 * s 
    b2 = b1 * s

```
Tint (lighten) 
If the value of pixel p1 = (r1, g1, b1) and the amount of desired change is t (<= 1.0) 
Then the value of the new pixel, p2 = 
r2 = (t * r1) + (255 * (1.0 - t)) 
g2 = (t * g1) + (255 * (1.0 - t)) 
b2 = (t * b1) + (255 * (1.0 - t))
```

Comment: what is not working, and would you consider using numpy and matplotlib?

Comment: This is pretty easy for anyone who know whats up with python, it shouldn't be that hard...

Comment: you should write exactly and clearly what is not working and preferably show traceback or output of the bad result...